# Android Studio and Visual Studio database sharing

Tags: android, database, visual-studio, sqlite

i have a project that need me to create a website (with asp.net) and window app (with VB.net) on visual studio, and then i have to create an android application that can connect to the same database that the website and window app are using

i am only familiar with the built in database in visual studio (im a newbie),  android seems to run their database with sql lite, is there anyway for the android to connect to visual studio's database?..
can android create a database based on the mdf file of the visual studio?..

Comment: There is no "built in database in Visual Studio".  I assume that you are talking about SQL Server.  It does not matter what database you are using, or what database Android uses since everything is done through web services.  You need to learn about WFC, SOAP and REST.

Comment: what if all 3 of these are done on one pc locally?..